# CPP Builder and Ado Filter

Tags: ado, c++builder, c++builder-2010

I am using C++Builder 2010. I am filtering an ADOTable, in Edit1 OnChange I have:

```
    ADOTable1->Filter = "firstname like %" + Edit1->Text + "%";
```

It reports an error when typing in a space, ) and = sign
What is the proper way to type the filter?
Thanks

Comment: Does it work if you type words or single letters?

Comment: Yes it does. Only the mentioned characters cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need single quotes before and after the string you are passing to the [Filter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DB.TDataSet.Filter) property.

```cpp
// QuotedStr example
ADOTable1->Filter = "firstname like '%" + QuotedStr(Edit1->Text) + "%'";

// StringReplace example
System::String temp; 
temp = StringReplace(Edit1->Text, "'", "''", TReplaceFlags() << rfReplaceAll);
ADOTable1->Filter = "firstname like '%" + temp + "%'";
```

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Setting_the_Filter_Property) does not mention the **LIKE** operator, but [another website](http://www.teachitza.com/delphi/databasehowto.htm) I found suggests this is possible.

Comment: NVM I solved it this way: temp = StringReplace(Edit1->Text, "'", "''",
 TReplaceFlags() << rfReplaceAll);

Comment: I think the QuotedStr function does the same as the StringReplace you provided.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have C++ Builder but the below code works on Delphi that is very similar to C++ Builder:

```
    ADOTable1.filter := 'firstName LIKE '+ QuotedStr('%'+Trim(Edit1.Text)+'%') ;
```